# one error in a code maxonebordersize.java

Tags: java

the error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in a loop

```
public class MaxOneBorderSize {

    public static void setBorderMap(int[][] m, int[][] right, int[][] down) {
       if(m == null){
           return;
       }

   
        right = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
        down  = new  int[m.length][m[0].length];

  
        for(int row = 0; row <m.length;row++ ){
            for(int col = 0; col <m[0].length; col++){
                int index = 0;
                int tempCol = col;


                // 0 - N-1
                while(tempCol<m[0].length && m[row][tempCol] == 1){
                    tempCol++;
                    index++;
                }

                right[row][tempCol-1] = index;
            }
        }


        // 然后生成down的数据

        for(int row = 0; row <m.length;row++ ){
            for(int col = 0; col <m[0].length; col++){
                int index = 0;

                while(row<m.length&&m[row][col] == 1){
                    row++;
                    index++;
                }

                down[row-1][col] = index;
            }
        }
    }



    public static int getMaxSize(int[][] m) {
        int[][] right = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
        int[][] down = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
        setBorderMap(m, right, down); // O(N^2); +

        for (int size = Math.min(m.length, m[0].length); size != 0; size--) {
            if (hasSizeOfBorder(size, right, down)) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static boolean hasSizeOfBorder(int size, int[][] right, int[][] down) {
        for (int i = 0; i != right.length - size + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j != right[0].length - size + 1; j++) {
                if (right[i][j] >= size && down[i][j] >= size
                        && right[i + size - 1][j] >= size
                        && down[i][j + size - 1] >= size) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int[][] generateRandom01Matrix(int rowSize, int colSize) {
        int[][] res = new int[rowSize][colSize];
        for (int i = 0; i != rowSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j != colSize; j++) {
                res[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i != matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j != matrix[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = generateRandom01Matrix(7, 8);
        printMatrix(matrix);
        System.out.println(getMaxSize(matrix));
    }
}
```

1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0

I have completed the code to get the longest side of the rectangle consists of ‘1’. But the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException has occured in

```
for(int row = 0; row <m.length;row++ ){
            for(int col = 0; col <m[0].length; col++){
                int index = 0;
                int tempCol = col;


                // 0 - N-1
                while(tempCol<m[0].length && m[row][tempCol] == 1){
                    tempCol++;
                    index++;
                }

                right[row][tempCol-1] = index;
            }
        }
```

I don't have any idea about that.

Comment: Please add the exact and full exception to the question. This should explain what the index was trying to access when it was out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you have not handled exception for the condition tempCol = 0
which would make tempcol = -1 in the code and it will be out of bounds.

```
right[row][tempCol-1] = index;
```

There are two ways to handle this either use try catch or if else with proper condition

```
for(int row = 0; row <m.length;row++ ){
   for(int col = 0; col <m[0].length; col++){
     int index = 0;
     int tempCol = col;

     while(tempCol<m[0].length && m[row][tempCol] == 1){
       tempCol++;
       index++;
     }

     if(tempCol!=0){
       right[row][tempCol-1] = index;
     }
     else{
       right[row][tempCol] = index;
     }

   }
 }
```

There is same problem with the down array which has row-1.

Also next time posting a question use proper proportionate indentation.

**Exception：**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at MaxOneBorderSize.setBorderMap(MaxOneBorderSize.java:25)
    at MaxOneBorderSize.getMaxSize(MaxOneBorderSize.java:51)
    at MaxOneBorderSize.main(MaxOneBorderSize.java:96)
```